# Inequality $\frac{x-1}{(x+1)\sqrt{6-x-x^2}}\geq 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

**Problem:** Find the sum of the integer solutions to the inequality $$\frac{x-1}{(x+1)\sqrt{6-x-x^2}}\geq 0.$$

**My solution:** Denoting the LHS with $f(x)$, I first find the zeros of each factor of the function: $$\begin{array}{lcl}
x-1 & = & 0 \Leftrightarrow x_1=1\\
x+1 & = & 0 \Leftrightarrow x_2=-1\\
\sqrt{6-x-x^2} & = & 0 \Leftrightarrow x_3=-3 \ \ \text{and} \ \ x_4=2 
\end{array}$$

Setting these values up and checking the sign of $f(x)$ at and in between the zeroes, I find that $f(x)$ is undefined for $x\in (-\infty,-3)\cup (2,\infty)$ and at $x=-1.$ In $(-1,1)$ the function is negative, in $(1,2)$ the function is positive, but there are no integers in between. At $x=1$ we have that $f(1)=0$, so for this value the inequality holds. Furthermore, in the interval $(-3,-1)$, the function is positive, and the only integral value here is $x=-2$.

Thus, the sum of the integer solutions is $-2+1 = -1.$ The answer is correct, but this hole thing took me 30 minutes to do, and I have 30 questions in this test and 2 hours. Seems there should me a much faster solution? Anyone has a trick up the sleeve?

Answer (score 0):

The domain gives $-3<x<2$ and by the interval's method we obtain:
$-3<x<-1$ or $1\leq x<2$, which gives $\{1,-2\}$ and the answer:
$-1$.

Comment: What is the interval's method?

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{x-1}{x+1} $ has the same signum than $(x-1)(x+1) $ which is positive at $D_1=(-\infty,-1]\cup (-1,+\infty) $.

the denominator is defined at
$D_2=(-3,2) $ and it is positive, so the solution is

$$D_1\cap D_2=(-3,-1)\cup [1,2) .$$

we apply the rule which says that
$Ax^2+Bx+C $ has the signum of $A $
 outside the roots and $-A $ between .

Comment: What do you mean by "$\frac{x-1}{x+1}$ has the same sign than..." ??

Comment: $a.b $ and $a/b $ have the same signum.

Comment: I think your English is confusing me. The sentence should be "...has the same signum as..." not "than". How do you know that the denominator is defined in (-3,2)?

Comment: @Parseval i edited it. thanks.